# How to send data from input using asp-route attribute?

Tags: forms, asp.net-core

I'm using this code to call controller with action.
I want to send data from input tag inside asp-route-data.

```html
<span><label><b>Korisnik :</b></label></span>
<br />
<input type="text" name="korisnik" id="korisnik" size="40" height="25" />
<br />
<br />
<span><label><b>Lozinka :</b></label></span>
<br />
<input type="password" name="lozinka" id="lozinka" size="40" height="25" />
<br />
<br />
<button type="submit" title="Login" class="btnLogin" asp-controller="Members" asp-route-username=a sp-route-password="" asp-action="LoginUser">
```

So, asp-route-username should be the value from input korisnik.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly (of which I'm not so sure) I think the answer to your problem is it use `<form>` tag. Then instead of appling the `asp-route` attributes on `<button>` tag, apply them on `<form>` tag:

```html
<form asp-controller="Members" asp-action="LoginUser" asp-route-username="a" asp-route-password="">
    <span><label><b>Korisnik :</b></label></span>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="korisnik" id="korisnik" size="40" height="25" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <span><label><b>Lozinka :</b></label></span>
    <br />
    <input type="password" name="lozinka" id="lozinka" size="40" height="25" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <button type="submit" title="Login" class="btnLogin"></button>
</form>
```

Be sure to check out the official ASP.NET Core documentation on [how to work with forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms).

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `username` and `password` using `asp-route-{value}`, it will show these information in the url which is not recommended.

If you just want to pass the two input values from view to controller, you need to modify `name` attribute of input to match the action parameters.For example:

View:

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Members" asp-action="LoginUser">
    <span><label><b>Korisnik :</b></label></span>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="username" id="korisnik" size="40" height="25" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <span><label><b>Lozinka :</b></label></span>
    <br />
    <input type="password" name="password" id="lozinka" size="40" height="25" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <button type="submit" title="Login" class="btnLogin"></button>
</form>
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginUser(string username,string password)
```

Comment: I tried this code but it want work. I put breakpoint in controller action to se value I get but it looks like it never gets there.

Comment: I managed to get it to work but username and password has null values.

Comment: Do you match the name property to action parameters?Could you update your code in your question(view and controller)?